# How to read files from resource folder of spring boot application using javascipt

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, maven

I have some files under resources/test/feature/a.feature , b.feature like that , i want read those files using javascript , and the jacascript file location is resources/test/js/read.js. I am using below code to read

```
function processFeatures() {
    var features = [];
    var featuresResources = $resources("feature/.*?\\.feature");
    for(var i in featureResources) {
        var feature = JSON.parse($eval(featureResources[i].content))
        features.push(feature);
    }
    return features;
}
```

This code works when i run the application from intellij, but when i build a jar file and then run the jar file separately that time it fails to read. I printed the featuresResources , that time it giving empty response.

What needs to do in that case.

Comment: 1) is this `js` file part of spring boot application? 2) If yes how is it served to the client? 3) How is `$resources` defined? Please update your question as it misses necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to use java code instead of java script or call code from java script to read file
But in your case,
its all because of jar file doesn't contain file structure in same manner as you see in your IDE verify your file path in built folder which have final structure which server will run.